# dplyr::count and group_by misfunction

Tags: r

Anyone knows why I all of sudden get this error message?

```
library(dplyr)

d <- wrapr::build_frame( "ID" , "OP", "DATE" | 1 , "A" , "2001-01-02" | 1 , "B" , "2015-04-25" | 2 , "A" , "2000-04-01" | 3 , "D" , "2014-04-07" | 4 , "C" , "2012-12-01" | 4 , "A" , "2005-06-16" | 4 , "D" , "2009-01-20" | 4 , "B" , "2009-01-20" | 5 , "A" , "2010-10-10" | 5 , "B" , "2003-11-09" | 6 , "B" , "2004-01-09" )

d%>%count(ID)
```

Generates the following error:

```
Error in vapply(.x, .f, .mold, ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE) : 
  values must be type 'logical',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'integer'
```

Comment: I could't reproduce the issue. can you try `d %>% dplyr::count(ID)`

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   count(ID)
#  ID n
#1  1 2
#2  2 1
#3  3 1
#4  4 4
#5  5 2
#6  6 1
```